# Since heat is such a problem in modern computers, why aren't we using Tofolli gates and reversible computing?

Tags: digital-logic

Today the Tofolli Gate is largely studied for its application to quantum computing, but Tofolli invented it in 1980 to perform reversible computing with electronic circuits in order to address the problem of heat and cooling.

(For those who are unaware, the Tofolli Gate is one of the building blocks of quantum computers, although it was not developed for that purpose.)

Cooling wasn't much of a problem in the 1980s, but it emerged as a serious problem in the 2000s and it remains one today. Given that reversible computation is universal, and given that there's no reason why reversible computers can't be fast, why are EE designers not using reversible computation and Tofolli gates in modern designs?

Here's an article from EE|Times in 2004 which said ["a group of researchers at the Department of Computer and Information Science and Engineering (CISE) at the University of Florida is working to make a reality a radical idea for making computers more energy efficient ” as well as smaller and faster."](https://www.eetimes.com/are-reversible-computers-more-energy-efficient-faster-2/)

In September 2017, Peter Denning and Ted Lewis had a big article in American Scientist, saying reversible computing ["may be the future of computing"](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/computers-that-can-run-backwards)

IEEE Spectrum had a similar article in August 2017, stating ["It’s time to embrace reversible computing, which could offer dramatic improvements in energy efficiency"](https://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/hardware/the-future-of-computing-depends-on-making-it-reversible)

So why aren't we using Tofolli gates and reversible computing?

Comment: Because every popular science article you read is hype to get funding. Technology X is only a few years away (if we get more money for research, hurry to invest).

Comment: From the IEEE article you linked: "So the time is indeed ripe now to pursue this technology, as it will probably take at least a decade for reversible computers to become practical."  So... Not practical now.

Comment: Looks like the perpetual movement machine. It will never work.

Comment: it appears that the Tofolli Gate is simply some pencil lines on paper at this time

Comment: this question makes me think of Isaac Asimov's short story The Last Question .... https://physics.princeton.edu/ph115/LQ.pdf

Comment: Because it's a hypothetical idea and we don't have an actual way to make a Toffoli gate that won't create heat anyway, but they're harder to use to make computers?

Comment: I added some background on Toffoli gates, which are widely used in quantum computers...

Answer (score 5):

> Given that reversible computation is universal, and given that there's no reason why reversible computers can't be fast, why are EE designers not using reversible computation and Tofolli gates in modern designs?

The wikipedia article on the [Von Neumann-Landauer limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle) explains this nicely:

> A so-called logically-reversible computation, in which no information is erased, may in principle be carried out without releasing any heat. This has led to considerable interest in the study of reversible computing. Indeed, without reversible computing, increases in the number of computations-per-joule-of-energy-dissipated must come to a halt by about 2050: because the limit implied by Landauer's principle will be reached by then, according to Koomey's law.
>
> At 20 °C (room temperature, or 293.15 K), the Landauer limit represents an energy of approximately 0.0175 eV, or 2.805 zJ. Theoretically, room‑temperature computer memory operating at the Landauer limit could be changed at a rate of one billion bits per second (1Gbps) with energy being converted to heat in the memory media at the rate of only 2.805 trillionths of a watt (that is, at a rate of only 2.805 pJ/s). Modern computers use millions of times as much energy per second.[2][3][4]

Reversible computing is not used because we have at least several decades worth of power scaling still possible with conventional irreversible computing.  Until we reach the Landauer limit, the heat generated from the entropy of operations is insignificant, and reversible computing has no practical application.

Comment: You can get power dissipation improvements using reversible computing before you actually hit the Landauer limit with conventional computing.

Comment: @Matt In practice that would be very difficult because reversible gates must have more inputs and outputs than conventional gates, and so have higher losses. If you are not already at the Landauer Limit where your conventional losses are approaching zero, the reversible gate probably uses a lot more power due to these losses.

Comment: You overestimate how much more complicated reversible gates are. https://www3.nd.edu/~lent/pdf/nd/FCN_ReversibleAndAdiabaticHanninenLentSniderBlair2014.pdf You don't need to even be all that close to the Landauer limit for there to be substantial power savings.

Comment: @Matt - that paper focuses entirely consumption from the computation in isolation, and the authors acknowledge this. Gains diminish over 100 MHz. They also use an 11(!!) phase clock - all your power gains from reversible logic implementation have evaporated there! As I said in my answer, for the time being, it's an interesting research topic :)

Comment: @awjlogan Yes... It is currently a research area. But my point was that you can beat conventional computing with reversible computation without needing to beat the Landauer limit, and the paper shows this. Im not making claims that its ready for production, or that there arent other things to work out. But now you have moved the goalposts if you are worried about power losses in the power supply, since we were talking about the logic circuitry. But thats a solvable problem anyway.

Comment: @Matt No goalposts moved - it is a system problem so if sub-block X uses 20% less power but you need to generate 10 more clocks using 20% more power, then you've not improved anything, just made it someone else's problem to deal with :)

Comment: @awjlogan My claim was that reversible computing can beat conventional computing power dissipation well before you are at the Landauer limit. This paper demonstrates that. The power supply issue is the same problem now as it will be once conventional computing at the limit. Therefore if this model of reversible computing can beat the Landauer limit, then its power benefits outlined in this paper can also be realized before getting to the limit, as I claimed. (If the clock/power supply issue cant be solved, thats another problem, and none of this works anyway.)

Comment: @Matt That's the whole nub of the question "Why is reversible computing not used" though. There's no debate that this _are_ savings to be made (substantial as the paper shows), but it must be balanced with the system as a whole.

Comment: @awjlogan I dont generally disagree with you, but we are talking about different things. My complaint is with the statement "Until we reach the Landauer limit, the heat generated from the entropy of operations is insignificant, and reversible computing has no practical application." Which we now both agree is false.

Answer (score 1):

As `jsotola` mentioned in the comments, just looking at lines on paper, it sounds great and why wouldn't you? Unfortunately, hidden in the lines, is the actual implementation. Transistors on modern processes are *awful*, they are nothing like the perfect switch that is implied. The leakage power is very high (*static power consumption*), so modern processors spend a lot of time switched off to mitigate against this. Power is also consumed when the inputs change (*dynamic power consumption*).

Both static and dynamic power scale with the number of transistors. The Tofolli gate uses a lot more transistors per logical operation, so any energy saving in terms of information entropy is swamped by the higher transistor count it implies.

Also, economically, factor in the huge investment (many billions of dollars, trillions probably?) into current technology. There has to be a very compelling reason to abandon that, and we're not at that point yet. The CMOS Tofolli gate currently sounds like a good academic project to write compilers and libraries to compare against current technology on the fab shuttle service (this is not a bad thing!).

Comment: So the issue is really static leakage? Doesn't SRAM memory have this same problem, then? Shouldn't SRAM generate more heat than DRAM?

Comment: @vy32 As always, it's a balance - if you design a MOSFET that's got low leakage, it's likely to have high dynamic power consumption. This impacts SRAM - low leakage = slower SRAM. Also, the processor does not exist in a vacuum and shuttling data between the core and the off chip main memory takes another "huge" amount of the power budget. The principal advantage of DRAM over SRAM is the density, rather than the power.